# Programmatic export from Word to wdFormatFlatXML silently produces the binary format instead of the XML format for some documents

Tags: vba, ms-word, file-conversion, word-2007

I have batch task (a VBA sub in a Word document with macros) that converts a large number of Word documents (in .doc format) into the Word XML format (the one with namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/...).

I do the conversion like this (the following snipped runs in a loop):

```
Set oDoc = Documents.Open(pathOriginal)
oDoc.SaveAs FileName:=pathXML, FileFormat:=wdFormatFlatXML
```

This generally works for a couple of thousand of our files. But for a handful of files, the generated file is not in XML format, instead it is saved in the original (.doc) format. No error is reported. I could not find any documentation of this phenomenon. I cannot find anything special about the files that cause the omitted conversion.

Has anyone experienced this problem? Any suggestions how to fix it?

**EDIT**

The problematic files all open up a password dialog. 
(However, some other files that have a password, too, convert fine.)

It turns out that changing the second line to

```
oDoc.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatFlatXML, Password:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False
```

solves the problem.

It would still be nice to understand whether this is intended behaviour?

Comment: Haven't experienced and no suggestions, but a clarificaiton please: does the problem occur at random, or is the behaviour repeatable for any given file? (Also, if it's random, does it only start occurring after, say, 1000 files, or can it occur very early in the batch?)

Comment: No, it is repeatable. Actually, it is also repeatable when I save the respective files to XML manually using the Save as dialog of Word.

Comment: It turns out all the problematic files open up a password dialog (although others that have a password convert fine). I have edited the post with the bug fix that works for me now - but I still don't understand why Word silently changed the format for some of the files but not the others (even when they had a password).

Comment: I would also put `ReadOnly:=True` to `Documents.Open`. May be some objects in those docs cannot be converted? Also what you get if a document contains Macros?

Comment: Thanks, I have added ReadOnly:=True, too. None of the documents contains macros, some have set "recommend read only", some have set a password, some are forms where the form is protected. With ReadOnly := True on Documents.Open and Password:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False on Save, all files convert fine, now. So my problem is solved for now. I am still puzzled how the omitted conversion can happen so silently. I would have expected an error.